# How do I skip NaN values in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, nan, astropy

I have a big fits file I'm working with in astropy, and I'm randomising 100 sets of coordinates to work with (calculating sky noise), but because the fits file I'm working with is an image from a telescope, the image is skewed. Because of this, large sections of the file are just NaN values. I want to avoid the areas with NaNs so I can only analyse areas with actual pixel values. How do I do this in the loop I've written?

```
N = 100
x = np.random.uniform(60, og.shape[0]-60, N).astype(int) # random co-rdinate within a boarder
y = np.random.uniform(60, og.shape[1]-60, N).astype(int)

n = np.zeros(N)

def dntp(x, y): # 'og' is my big fits file
    box = og[x-30:x+30, y-31:y+30] # creating a box the same size as mask
    pht = mask*box
    mjy = ((photfnu*pht)/et)*1e6 # converting to microjanksies
    return mjy
        
for i in range(N):
        if np.sum(np.isnan(og[x[i]])) == 0 & np.sum(np.isnan(og[y[i]])) == 0:
                n[i] = np.sum(dntp(x[i],y[i]))
```

When looking at the values of n the loop gives me, I get all 0 values, any ideas?

Comment: Is your code attempting to skip NaNs? If you run without the `if` condition, what would be undesired about `n` array?

Comment: Instead of asking "how do I do this in the loop I've written?" a more useful question might be "how do I do this?" (where the existing code might not be the most appropriate approach).  Could you provide a small reproducible example?  We don't know what `og` or `mask` are, for example.  I realize `og` is an image from a FITS file but having an example might help.